# Calling methods with objects trouble

Tags: java, object

So, I need to do this for part of my homework :

Create a method in the Customer class called `hasMoreMoneyThan(Customer c)`
which returns `true` if the customer calling the method has more money than the
customer `c`, otherwise it should return `false`.

I am looking to be pointed in the right direction for the line that says "the customer calling the method"

This is very confusing to me and doesn't make sense, this my `Customer` is a class.

Here is the necessary code :

```
public class Customer
{ 
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private float money;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }


    public Customer(String n, int a, float m)
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
        money = m;

   }
```

I started writing the method:

```
public boolean hasMoreMoneyThan(Customer c)
{

}
```

But am not sure how to call that with my `Customer` object (which I think the question is asking.

Other relevant code :

```
public class StoreTestProgram {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Customer[]    result;
        Store         walmart;

        walmart = new Store("Walmart off Innes");
        walmart.addCustomer(new Customer("Amie", 14, 100));

    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that "the customer calling the method" is poorly worded. I'm not surprised that this causes confusion when it is put like this. The *runtime* is the only one calling methods. It should be "the customer *on which* the method is called".

Answer (score 2):

When a method is called on an object, the objects variables are in the current scope. In this case, the 'customer calling the method' is the object that the method is being called on (object being an instance of the class).

So, if `boolean hasMoreMoneyThan(Customer c)` is being called on `Customer a`, then you should think of it as asking `Customer a has more money than Customer c?`.

You can use the `this` keyword to refer to the current object (to help the reader differentiate from `Customer c`).

So, in your `hasMoreMoneyThan` method, you can compare `this.money` with `c.money`.

And to call this method, you need a reference to the current customer and the customer you want to compare with. You could do something like:

```
Customer currentCustomer = new Customer(...
Customer customerToCompareWith = new Customer(...

if (currentCustomer.hasMoreMoneyThan(customerToCompareWith)) {
    // do something
}
```

**Edit** Let's try a different example. Let's say you want a method to know whether a customer is older than another customer. That code might look like:

```
public boolean isOlderThan(Customer c) {
    return this.age > c.age;
}
```

And to call the method:

```
if (currentCustomer.isOlderThan(customerToCompareWith)) {
    // the current customer is older
} else {
    // the current customer is not older
}
```

Comment: The edit makes me understand this more, I understand now how we can reference objects and call the methods, thanks!:)

Comment: @SpencerVreugdenhil-Beauclerc If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is how you reference an object from methods that are members of an object. `this.money ><=? c.money`
if in your constructor you you used `public Customer(String name, int age, float money)` you would use `this.name= name` instead of `name= n` to clear up ambiguity.